# E/ReactNativeJS: Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing code with react-native-ble-plx library but I encountered such an error. service and characteristic uuids are correct. Where could there be a mistake?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Platform, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { BleManager } from 'react-native-ble-plx';

export default class Bleconnect extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.manager = new BleManager()

    this.state = {info: "", values: {}}
   
   
    this.sensors = {
   
      0: "Temperature",
      1: "Accelerometer",
      2: "Humidity",
      3: "Magnetometer",
     
      
    }
    
    }

    serviceUUID() {
    return "000f0f0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
  }

  notifyUUID(num) {
   return num
  }

 


  info(message) {
      this.setState({info: message})
    }

  error(message) {
      this.setState({info: "ERROR: " + message})
    }

  updateValue(key, value) {
      this.setState({values: {...this.state.values, [key]: value}})
    }

    componentDidMount(){
    const subscription = this.manager.onStateChange((state) => {
      if (state === 'PoweredOn') {
        this.scanAndConnect();
        subscription.remove();
      }
    }, true);
  }
  async requestPermission() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        this.setState({permissionStatus:'granted'});
      }else if(granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.DENIED) {
        this.setState({permissionStatus:'denied'});
      }else{

      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }

    scanAndConnect(){
      this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
        
            this.info("Scanning...")
            console.log(device)
            
            if (error) {
              this.error(error.message)
              return
        }

       
        if (device.name == 'Healthy Race' ) {
          this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
          device.connect()
            .then((device) => {
              this.info("Discovering services and characteristics ")
              return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()
            })
           .then((device) => {
             this.info("SetupNotification")
             return this.setupNotifications(device)
           })
            .catch((error) => {
              this.error(error.message)
             
            });
        }

      });
    }


    async setupNotifications(device) {

        for (const id in this.sensors) {

          const service = this.serviceUUID(id)
          
          const characteristicN = this.notifyUUID(id)

          device.readCharacteristicForService( service, characteristicN,(error, characteristic) => {
            if (error) {
              this.error(error.message)
              return
            }
            this.updateValue(characteristic.uuid, characteristic.value)
          })
        }
      }

    render() {
       return (
         <View>
           <Text>{this.state.info}</Text>
           {Object.keys(this.sensors).map((key) => {
          return <Text key={key}>
                   {this.sensors[key] + ": " + (this.state.values[this.notifyUUID(key)] || "-")}
                 </Text>
        })}
         </View>
       )
     }

}
```

I tried some methods but it didn't work. There is something missing somewhere and I guess I can't see it. I am sending different characteristicUUIDs within the same serviceUUID.

Thanks